# How do i deal with SSL using sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

i have no past experience with using sockets into any other programming language, but now, i have to make a request using a service API that accepts Sockets only.

My code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/LhM8Nkpw) .

I dont know if i am proceding correctly, because the `ValidateCertificate` method is returning false.The "errors" parameter is not equal to "none", its value is : `CertificateNameMissmatch | CertificateChainErrors`

Since this is my first socket application, i dont know what may be happening here.

The service i am trying to access, makes use of SSL and this `Socket API` is used to query their database.

this is the code that is first executed:

```
        // Creating SSLClient
        m_sslClient = new SSLClient ("localhost","200.245.207.155",3395);

        // Encoding and Converting Struct to String
        layoutAsString = CrednetStructs.StructureToString (new CrednetStructs.InputLayout ("","","",""));

        // Writting message to Stream
         m_sslClient.WriteMessage (layoutAsString);
```

Where the InputLayout is the parameter for the socket request that can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ZvCMTe03). Its a struct.

Let me know if there is any aditional information i may have missed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe the hostname your connecting to '200.245.207.155' might not be the same as what is in the certificate, i.e. it might be 'www.server.com'

Comment: The most common reason for a `CertificateChainError` is a self-signed certificate.

Comment: What you mean by "Self-signed certificate?"

Also, how do i know the right server name ? These values were the ones i've found at the product manual

Comment: The server name is usually in the CN=... part of the DN, for example, when I go to google mail and look at the cert, it shows me CN = mail.google.com